# Bookshelf cascade delete

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have two models `Company` and `CompanyAdmin`. A model Company has many CompanyAdmins. I am trying to delete CompanyAdmins when a parent Company is deleted, using bookshelf plugin `bookshelf-cascade-delete`. I also use **knex** to connect **mysql** db. 
Here are my models:

```
const db = bookshelf(connection);
db.plugin(cascadeDelete);

const Company = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'company',
    idAttribute: 'id',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    company_admins: function () { return this.hasMany(CompanyAdmin); }, // console.log(this);
}, {
    dependents: ['company_admins'],
});

const CompanyAdmin = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'company_admin',
    idAttribute: 'id',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    company: function () { return this.belongsTo(Company) },
});
```

When I **console.log(this)** in *company_admins* function, I get this data:

```
ModelBase {
  tableName: 'company',
  idAttribute: 'id',
  hasTimestamps: true,
  company_admins: [Function: company_admins] }
```

Here is my DELETE route handler:

```
.delete((req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
        Company.forge({
            id: req.user.attributes.company_id,
        })
        .destroy()
        .then(() => {
            res.status(200)
            .json({
                status: 200,
                error: false,
            });
            req.logout();
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500)
            .json({
                status: 500,
                error: err.message,
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401)
        .json({
            status: 401,
            message: 'User not authenticated',
        });
    }
});
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasMany' of undefined

Anybody with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Error was in importing bookshelf.
The code I was using before was:

```
import bookshelf from 'bookshelf';
const db = bookshelf(connection);
```

And the correct import of bookshelf look like this:

```
const db = require('bookshelf')(connection);
```

Not quite sure why the previous code didn't work, but the modified version works well!